# Use mining to prevent DDOS attacks on websocket: Is this a viable solution?

Tags: security, networking, hash, websocket, ddos

I'm thinking whether the following way is a good way to completely and totally prevent ddos on my server. My idea is to use the same mechanism of cryptocurrency mining (bitcoin, with sha256 or any other hash) to prevent DDOS.

Note: I'm not suggesting to mine cryptocurrency per se. I'm suggesting to use the same mechanism to avoid [Sybil attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sybil_attack).

**Why does idea look appealing to me?** Because creating a mined hash is expensive, but verifying it is super-cheap. it costs only calculating a hash once.

**What does mining mean, in a nutshell?** It means that there's a specific chunk of data (say a session id, or a JWT token, that can be stored in the server in a performant NoSQL server), and the user (or the miner in cryptocurrency) has to create a hash that matches certain criteria. For example, if we use SHA256, we can define the difficulty as the required number of the leading zeros in the 256-bit resulting number from the hash. More zeros make the probability of finding that hash more difficult.

**How does it work?**: A user would take the session token (which is created by the server), and combine it with a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) (number used once), and calculate the hash in their frontend (through WASM, or otherwise with javascript). Since the user cannot reverse-engineer SHA256, all he can do is keep changing the nonce again, and again and again, until he finds a nonce that creates a hash that satisfies the required difficulty.

[image]

The graph shows the probability of finding a block (finding the correct nonce) in Bitcoin, where the difficulty is chosen to make it 10 minutes. Changing the difficulty will shift this curve and change its width proportionally.

**How long does it take the server to verify?** Practically zero. Just calculate the hash once and ensure that it matches the given difficulty, and that authorizes the user to make any anonymous request. Notice that none of this requires authentication with usernames and password. This is all anonymous. Authenticated users don't need to do this as their credentials can be banned from the system. This is all for anonymous users (and possibly attackers).

**The result:** The user will have to calculate this hash with this difficulty before making any request to the server. Once the user succeeds, the mined authentication token can be stored in a cookie to be reused by the user. If the user fails to provide the requested hash, his connection request will be abruptly reject, and thus preventing a DDOS attack with sock-puppets.

**[ASIC](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/3kj5dw/what-is-an-asic-miner-bitmain-monero-ethereum) resistance**: Using SHA256 is not recommended because there's specialized hardware that can calculate it very fast, leading to a possible coordinated attack. There are hashes that are hard to print on hardware, such as Scrypt and Argon2.

**Choosing the difficulty**: The difficulty can be static (which I wouldn't recommend), or can be dynamic to change with the load on the network. When a high network load exists, the required difficulty is increased. This basically will act as a filter and protect the network during DDOS attack times, and never affect the users, as users normally wouldn't care to wait 10 seconds to create a session. In case of really high load, the users can either choose to compute the expensive nonce, or come back later. The hosting company also can decide whether an expansion of the infrastructure is required based on the difficulty chart over time.

Is this a sound plan to protect against DDOS on websocket and similar public protocols? I would like to implement this on my server.

Comment: security design questions are usually off-topic on stackoverflow. This might be on topic on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/). FYI, this idea of [client puzzles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_Puzzle_Protocol) has been around for a long time now.

Comment: I'll post this there, thanks for the hint. However, I would disagree that this is off-topic.

Comment: How is it a programming question?

Comment: It's a design aspect.

Comment: It's security design, hence off-topic.

Comment: @JamesKPolk sorry buddy. I'm not willing to keep shooting back and forth. Better focus our energy on the real problem ;-)

Comment: Have you considered that the time taken for your server to accept a client/check if they have the correct token can be, in itself, employed as a DDOS attack?  Granted there would need to be far more saturation since the workload is small, but you can't "totally prevent ddos" by doing this.

Comment: I don't understand, Sybil attack is an attack on peer-2-peer networks. How is this related to web server?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark There's no silver bullet to everything, but trade-offs. The verification of the hash is super-cheap. It just takes decoding a string and calculating a hash. Right? Please explain more what it's that can be used as DDOS in the protocol.

Comment: @Zergatul Sybil attack refers to any system where a single user utilizes many fake connections to act as if they're many people. Some people would even argue that using `axel` to download on Linux is a kind of Sybil attack.

Answer (score 0):

Since a DDOS operates from multiple systems on multiple connections it is easy to counteract if you just write a script that will request a new SHA256 hash from the server for each individual connection will clog your server. They do not need to reverse engineer but just generate 'session tokens' for each individual connection requesting access to the server.

Comment: Calculating SHA256 (or any reasonable hash) is incredibly cheap... we're talking milliseconds. An attacker will need hundreds of thousands of sock-puppets, if not millions, to succeed at this level, since the bandwidth will never be an issue, and the clogging will be only due to computations of a token/user. Did I get this wrong?

Comment: Verifying the hashes logically seems to check out. Is what you are trying to say here is as the quantity of users increases the mining difficulty for hashes increase and as a result will constrain the service when the server load is high?

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on how you set the difficulty of finding the nonce. It can be as you described it (and as I mentioned in the last paragraph), correlated with the amount of users, such that it triggers a high difficulty when a DDOS attack happens, making it very expensive to attack and relatively cheap for honest users. Keep in mind that a consistent high-load means that the infrastructure has to be expanded.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: You're assuming the DDOS attacker will try to solve the puzzle. If the DDOS attacker simply sends wrong answers as fast as he can then you have to do more work than the attacker per hash.

Comment: @JamesKPolk keep in mind that blocking ips is always on the table. So an address spamming can be blocked temporarily. Otherwise no need to address this as a "distributed" attack.

Answer (score 0):

It should work in some way and protect from simple attacks. But you can improve it, by requesting dynamic hash difficulty on different requests.

For example, you have 2 pages, one displays data with specific record in db (by using primary key), second does difficult search, and sometimes there is no necessary index in db to do search fast, or page displays a lot of results. Attacker would like to DDOS second page and make the search as slow as possible.

You can setup low difficulty for first page, and high for second. The main idea can be: If you want to take `x` CPU time on server, spend `c * x` of your CPU time.

If you request hash only once, attacker can calculate necessary nonce and do million of requests by using single cookie.

Comment: I see what you mean, and it makes sense, however, keep in mind that if an attacker tries to do a request a million times after being authenticated, we could just de-authenticate him again.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist agree, de-authenticate should work